# Кросс-компиляция модуля ядра для DD-WRT

Tags: linux, kernel, кросс-компиляция, mips, dd-wrt

Добрый день! Я пытаюсь скомпилировать драйвер сетевого адаптера, чтобы подключить его к своему роутеру. Но поскольку я нуб, у меня это не очень-то получается. Прошу вас о помощи!

Итак, что мы имеем:

Роутер: D-LINK DIR-320

Прошивка: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (10/10/09) mini-usb-ftp

Подключаемое устройство: WI-FI адаптер TP-LINK TL-WN725N V2

Драйвер: хттп://static.tp-link.com/res/down/soft/TL-WN725N_V2_150911.zip

Тулчейн: хттп://download1.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv2/downloads/toolchains/toolchains.tar.xz

Ядро Linux: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.4/linux-2.4.37.tar.gz

Компилирую на: Ubuntu Linux 16 x86-64

В директории с файлами драйвера, я отредактировал Makfile, как указано в руководстве:

> ARCH ?= mips
>   CROSS_COMPILE ?=~/temp/toolchain-mipsel_gcc4.1.2/bin/mipsel-linux-gcc
>   KVER := 2.4.37
>   KSRC ?= ~/temp/linux-2.4.37

где ARCH - архитектура, CROSS_COMPILE - путь к тулчейну, KVER - версия ядра, KSRC - путь к ядру Linux.

Когда я выполняю команду sudo make, система выдает следующие сообщения:

```
"******************************************" 
"NO SKRC,we will use default KSRC" 
"******************************************" 
make ARCH=mips CROSS_COMPILE=~/temp/toolchain-mipsel_gcc4.1.2/bin/mipsel-linux-gcc -C ~/temp/linux-2.4.37 M=/home/fadeev/temp/TL-WN725N_V2_150911/Driver modules 
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37' 
make -C arch/mips/tools CFLAGS="-D__KERNEL__ -I/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fno-builtin-strpbrk -fno-builtin-sprintf -fomit-frame-pointer -I /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/asm/gcc -G 0 -mno-abicalls -fno-pic -pipe -DMODULE -mlong-calls -DMODVERSIONS -include /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/linux/modversions.h" MAKING_MODULES=1 modules 
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/arch/mips/tools' 
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/arch/mips/tools' 
make -C kernel CFLAGS="-D__KERNEL__ -I/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fno-builtin-strpbrk -fno-builtin-sprintf -fomit-frame-pointer -I /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/asm/gcc -G 0 -mno-abicalls -fno-pic -pipe -DMODULE -mlong-calls -DMODVERSIONS -include /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/linux/modversions.h" MAKING_MODULES=1 modules 
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/kernel' 
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/kernel' 
make -C drivers CFLAGS="-D__KERNEL__ -I/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fno-builtin-strpbrk -fno-builtin-sprintf -fomit-frame-pointer -I /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/asm/gcc -G 0 -mno-abicalls -fno-pic -pipe -DMODULE -mlong-calls -DMODVERSIONS -include /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/linux/modversions.h" MAKING_MODULES=1 modules 
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers' 
make -C acpi modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/acpi' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/acpi' 
make -C atm modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/atm' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/atm' 
make -C block modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/block' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/block' 
make -C cdrom modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/cdrom' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/cdrom' 
make -C char modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/char' 
make -C pcmcia modules 
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/char/pcmcia' 
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/char/pcmcia' 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/char' 
make -C hotplug modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/hotplug' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/hotplug' 
make -C ide modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/ide' 
make -C arm modules 
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/ide/arm' 
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/ide/arm' 
make -C legacy modules 
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/ide/legacy' 
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/ide/legacy' 
make -C pci modules 
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/ide/pci' 
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/ide/pci' 
make -C ppc modules 
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/ide/ppc' 
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/ide/ppc' 
make -C raid modules 
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/ide/raid' 
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/ide/raid' 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/ide' 
make -C ieee1394 modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/ieee1394' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/ieee1394' 
make -C md modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/md' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/md' 
make -C media modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/media' 
make -C radio modules 
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/media/radio' 
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/media/radio' 
make -C video modules 
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/media/video' 
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/media/video' 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/media' 
make -C message/fusion modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/message/fusion' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/message/fusion' 
make -C misc modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/misc' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/misc' 
make -C mtd modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/mtd' 
make -C chips modules 
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/mtd/chips' 
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/mtd/chips' 
make -C devices modules 
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/mtd/devices' 
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/mtd/devices' 
make -C maps modules 
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/mtd/maps' 
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/mtd/maps' 
make -C nand modules 
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/mtd/nand' 
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/mtd/nand' 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/mtd' 
make -C net modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/net' 
make -C appletalk modules 
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/net/appletalk' 
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/net/appletalk' 
make -C arcnet modules 
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/net/arcnet' 
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/net/arcnet' 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/net' 
make -C parport modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/parport' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/parport' 
make -C scsi modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/scsi' 
make -C pcmcia modules 
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/scsi/pcmcia' 
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/scsi/pcmcia' 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/scsi' 
make -C sound modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/sound' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/sound' 
make -C telephony modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/telephony' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/telephony' 
make -C usb/gadget modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/usb/gadget' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/usb/gadget' 
make -C video modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/video' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers/video' 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/drivers' 
make -C mm CFLAGS="-D__KERNEL__ -I/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fno-builtin-strpbrk -fno-builtin-sprintf -fomit-frame-pointer -I /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/asm/gcc -G 0 -mno-abicalls -fno-pic -pipe -DMODULE -mlong-calls -DMODVERSIONS -include /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/linux/modversions.h" MAKING_MODULES=1 modules 
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/mm' 
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/mm' 
make -C fs CFLAGS="-D__KERNEL__ -I/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fno-builtin-strpbrk -fno-builtin-sprintf -fomit-frame-pointer -I /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/asm/gcc -G 0 -mno-abicalls -fno-pic -pipe -DMODULE -mlong-calls -DMODVERSIONS -include /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/linux/modversions.h" MAKING_MODULES=1 modules 
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/fs' 
make -C nls modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/fs/nls' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/fs/nls' 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/fs' 
make -C net CFLAGS="-D__KERNEL__ -I/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fno-builtin-strpbrk -fno-builtin-sprintf -fomit-frame-pointer -I /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/asm/gcc -G 0 -mno-abicalls -fno-pic -pipe -DMODULE -mlong-calls -DMODVERSIONS -include /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/linux/modversions.h" MAKING_MODULES=1 modules 
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/net' 
make -C 802 modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/net/802' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/net/802' 
make -C atm modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/net/atm' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/net/atm' 
make -C core modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/net/core' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/net/core' 
make -C ipv4 modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/net/ipv4' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/net/ipv4' 
make -C ipv4/ipvs modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/net/ipv4/ipvs' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/net/ipv4/ipvs' 
make -C ipv4/netfilter modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/net/ipv4/netfilter' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/net/ipv4/netfilter' 
make -C ipv6/netfilter modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/net/ipv6/netfilter' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/net/ipv6/netfilter' 
make -C ipx modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/net/ipx' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/net/ipx' 
make -C netlink modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/net/netlink' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/net/netlink' 
make -C sched modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/net/sched' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/net/sched' 
make -C sctp modules 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/net/sctp' 
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/net/sctp' 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/net' 
make -C ipc CFLAGS="-D__KERNEL__ -I/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fno-builtin-strpbrk -fno-builtin-sprintf -fomit-frame-pointer -I /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/asm/gcc -G 0 -mno-abicalls -fno-pic -pipe -DMODULE -mlong-calls -DMODVERSIONS -include /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/linux/modversions.h" MAKING_MODULES=1 modules 
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/ipc' 
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/ipc' 
make -C lib CFLAGS="-D__KERNEL__ -I/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fno-builtin-strpbrk -fno-builtin-sprintf -fomit-frame-pointer -I /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/asm/gcc -G 0 -mno-abicalls -fno-pic -pipe -DMODULE -mlong-calls -DMODVERSIONS -include /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/linux/modversions.h" MAKING_MODULES=1 modules 
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/lib' 
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/lib' 
make -C crypto CFLAGS="-D__KERNEL__ -I/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fno-builtin-strpbrk -fno-builtin-sprintf -fomit-frame-pointer -I /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/asm/gcc -G 0 -mno-abicalls -fno-pic -pipe -DMODULE -mlong-calls -DMODVERSIONS -include /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/linux/modversions.h" MAKING_MODULES=1 modules 
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/crypto' 
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/crypto' 
make -C arch/mips/math-emu CFLAGS="-D__KERNEL__ -I/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fno-builtin-strpbrk -fno-builtin-sprintf -fomit-frame-pointer -I /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/asm/gcc -G 0 -mno-abicalls -fno-pic -pipe -DMODULE -mlong-calls -DMODVERSIONS -include /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/linux/modversions.h" MAKING_MODULES=1 modules 
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/arch/mips/math-emu' 
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/arch/mips/math-emu' 
make -C arch/mips/pci CFLAGS="-D__KERNEL__ -I/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fno-builtin-strpbrk -fno-builtin-sprintf -fomit-frame-pointer -I /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/asm/gcc -G 0 -mno-abicalls -fno-pic -pipe -DMODULE -mlong-calls -DMODVERSIONS -include /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/linux/modversions.h" MAKING_MODULES=1 modules 
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/arch/mips/pci' 
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/arch/mips/pci' 
make -C arch/mips/kernel CFLAGS="-D__KERNEL__ -I/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fno-builtin-strpbrk -fno-builtin-sprintf -fomit-frame-pointer -I /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/asm/gcc -G 0 -mno-abicalls -fno-pic -pipe -DMODULE -mlong-calls -DMODVERSIONS -include /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/linux/modversions.h" MAKING_MODULES=1 modules 
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/arch/mips/kernel' 
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/arch/mips/kernel' 
make -C arch/mips/mm CFLAGS="-D__KERNEL__ -I/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fno-builtin-strpbrk -fno-builtin-sprintf -fomit-frame-pointer -I /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/asm/gcc -G 0 -mno-abicalls -fno-pic -pipe -DMODULE -mlong-calls -DMODVERSIONS -include /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/linux/modversions.h" MAKING_MODULES=1 modules 
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/arch/mips/mm' 
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/arch/mips/mm' 
make -C arch/mips/lib CFLAGS="-D__KERNEL__ -I/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fno-builtin-strpbrk -fno-builtin-sprintf -fomit-frame-pointer -I /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/asm/gcc -G 0 -mno-abicalls -fno-pic -pipe -DMODULE -mlong-calls -DMODVERSIONS -include /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/include/linux/modversions.h" MAKING_MODULES=1 modules 
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/arch/mips/lib' 
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'modules'. 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/arch/mips/lib' 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37'
```

При этом никаких файлов с расширением .o в каталоге драйвера не появляется. Что означает "Nothing to be done for 'modules'", и как заставить его скомпилировать драйвер? Буду благодарен вам за любую помощь!

ЗЫ: прошу прощения за много буков.

Comment: Ссылка на Makefile: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9dVCpYUVoKULUdTMmMzZ0I4RUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Переместите, пожалуйста, Makefile на Pastebin или Github Gists

Comment: Лучше сюда. Пастбин не хранит вечно всё что в него заливают.

Comment: Пожалуйста: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/58951e70da3332f08e8b4f3f6aea4712

Comment: У вас универсальный makefile для современных ядер, непонятно, где вы и что меняли (нужен diff), и по симптомами похоже, что вызывается часть для 2.6+, т.е. обновите пост ещё и строкой запуска.

Comment: И да, кастомные тулчейны лучше разворачивать в /opt, хотя это если больше одного раза понадобится.

Comment: Результат выполнения diff: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9d4eef80aae1344e9c9d887f12a14dbb

Comment: Про строку запуска так и не понял, как я и писал, выполняю команду sudo make, если вы об этом.

Comment: для кросскомпиляции `sudo` не обязателен. Кроме того, ядро перед сборкой модуля, должно быть сконфигурировано и собрано.

Comment: @donRumata, я уже пробовал – файл слишком большой, не укладывается в ограничения по длине вопроса.

Comment: С чистого листа без правок фалов запустите`cd ~/temp/TL...; make ARCH=mips CROSS_COMPILE=mipsel-linux-  M=$PWD modules`. Перед этим в каталоге исходников ядра необходимо сгенерировать конфигурацию или подложить предыдущий вариант и пройтись по нему чем-то типа olddefconfig (такого не было в 2.4). Помимо этого, насколько я помню надо `make prepare` сказать. Там раньше мильён команд был, чтобы хоть как-то это в божеский вид привести. И я не совсем уверен, что скачанная вами версия вообще когда-либо собиралась под античные 2.4.x.y.

Answer (score 3):

> Я пытаюсь скомпилировать драйвер

Поясню, на всякий случай, может Вы не знаете: если Вы собираетесь компилировать драйвер, то вам нужно иметь две вещи:

1. Исходные тексты ядра. Точнее - файлы заголовков *.h для обращения к API ядра.
2. Объектные модули ядра, для того, что бы Ваш модуль *.ko можно было слинковать с данной версией ядра.

Поэтому, если у Вас есть директория, в которой уже лежат и исходы ядра и объектники, то повтороно ничего собирать уже не нужно. Для того, что бы один-единственный раз собрать ядро, нужно зайти в каталог с исходами ядра и выполнить команды (это у меня для : PowerPC) :

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnuspe/bin/:$PATH
./configure CC=powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnuspe-cc --host=ppc-linux
make
```

Существенно: в корне ядерных исходов обязательно должен лежать файл .config ! Откуда его взять - отдельная песня...

Только ПОСЛЕ сборки ядра Вы можете выдавать команду make modules. А, судя по сообщениям, которые Вы показали, именно эту команду и выдаёт Ваш скрипт. Естественно, что make не может собрать модули и говорит Вам об этом.

Comment: У меня конечно же файла .config в директории с исходниками ядра нет. Откуда же его взять?

Comment: м.б. в целевом устройстве в папке /boot либо иным способом из прошивки ковырять.

Comment: **Откуда же его взять?** - идеальный вариант - взять его из папки /proc на целевой системе. Тогда Вы получите именно то ядро, которое желаете. В этой папке должен быть файл config.gz. Его можно распечатать командой catz.

Comment: Если его нет, тогда надо запускать "make menuconfig" и долго и нудно выставлять те параметры, которые нужны на целевой платформе. Это ОЧЕНЬ долго и ОЧЕНЬ нудно... :-(

Comment: Я запускал make config и долго нудно выставлял параметры. =) Это не то же самое?

Comment: Оказывается файл .config в директории исходников ядра все-таки есть, я его просто не видел, потому что он скрытый. При вводе команды ./configure получаю "-sh: 20: ./config: not found". Да, что необходимо указывать в параметре "--host"? У меня платформа mips, не powerpc, файл компилятора называется mipsel-linux-gcc.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, в директории исходников линукса должен находиться файл configure? Так вот, его там нет.

Comment: **Это не то же самое?** - По смыслу - тоже самое. Но mrtuconfig работает в режиме псевдографики. Маленько полегче. Есть ещё xconfig - ещё более лёгкая версия.

Comment: **его там нет** И не может быть. Ведь исходники ядра - универсальны для всех платформ, а файл конфигурации затачивается не просто под платформу, а прямо под конкретный экземпляр. Только Вы сами можете знать - для чего Вы делаете это ядро.

Comment: **что необходимо указывать в параметре "--host"?** - это тоже достаточно длинная песня... Тип среды, на которой будет работать Ваш кросс-компиллер. В двух словах: это триада, которая задаёт (IMHO) железо-производитель-система. Именно так - через дефис. Конкретный список возможных вариантов (а не все варианты возможны) можно получить из документации по ядру. Попробуйте make help и посмотреть каталог doc в исходах ядра.

Comment: Да, но как мне быть с "-sh: 20: ./config: not found"?

Comment: В общем, попробовал скомпилировать ядро, командой make в директории исходников. Скомпилировалось много объектных файлов, пока на одном из этапов не появилась следующая ошибка: "".

Comment: mipsel-linux-ld -m elf32ltsmip -G 0 -static -n -T arch/mips/ld.script arch/mips/kernel/head.o arch/mips/kernel/init_task.o init/main.o init/version.o init/do_mounts.o \
  --start-group \
  arch/mips/kernel/kernel.o arch/mips/mm/mm.o kernel/kernel.o mm/mm.o fs/fs.o ipc/ipc.o arch/mips/math-emu/fpu_emulator.o \
   drivers/char/char.o drivers/block/block.o drivers/misc/misc.o drivers/net/net.o drivers/media/media.o \

Comment: net/network.o \
  arch/mips/lib/lib.a /home/fadeev/temp/linux-2.4.37/lib/lib.a \
  --end-group \
  -o vmlinux
mipsel-linux-ld:arch/mips/ld.script:6: parse error
make: *** [vmlinux] Ошибка 1